# JQuery not operator using .on('click')

Tags: jquery, html

I would like to know how to setup :not operator in jQuery. I have tried the code below but its not working

`$('#category-table tbody').on('click', 'tr',':not(input[type=button])', function () {`

What is my mistake in this area`':not(input[type=button])'`

Thank you!
John

Comment: i actually have two $('#category-table tbody').on('click', 'tr',':not(input[type=button])', function () { , the other is being used to higlight a row, and the other one is being used to retrieve a data, both functions as click event, i dont want to select the button when retrieve function is hit.

Answer (score 1):

According to the 1.7 jquery api http://api.jquery.com/on/
You should follow this configuration:

```
$().on(eventName, childSelector, callback)
```

Check this fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/bd40xrr8/1/

Comment: im clicking the row of a table but i need to exclude edit and delete button, but it is still happening. thnks for the answer,your code is not working. Edit and Delete button still involves.

Comment: here <button type="button" class="btn-edit btn btn-info btn-default">Edit</button>

Comment: @loki_thor It doesnt work because you where using input as selector, but the element selector should be "button", not "input". Check the fiddle in my updated answer.